# Unable to install elementary OS on a Gnome Box vm

Tags: release-juno, system-installation, virtualization

I'm running Gnome Boxes, trying out different distros (including elementary OS).

I can run the elementary OS liveUSB environment just fine, but when I try to install Elementary on my 25GB virtual disk, it always hangs (even the busy cursor stops animating).

(Currently running under Ubuntu-Budgie)

I'm willing to try it under qemu instead, if someone has some documentation on which settings to use.

[image: Hangs on "Configuring hardware..."]

Comment: Just wait a while. It may be doing something. By the way, if you press on the arrow it will show you some detailed information that would be useful to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have installed ok, even though it froze up. :)

Comment: If your problem is resolved and this is the answer of your problem, can you mark it like the correct answer, so it changes the status of your question to resolved into StackExchange system? It will be better to be clear what has to be done if somebody is in a simillar situation like yours.